# Order of contact splines

Tags: calculus, mathematica

If $f[x]$ and $g[x]$ is any pair of functions that have order of contact $m$ at $x=0$, then what is the order of contact of $f[x^2]$ and $g[x^2]$ at $x=0$?

Mathematica code:

```
Clear[f, g, x, k, derivativeorder]; 
m = 3; 
Column[Table[{derivativeorder[k], D[f[x^2], {x, k}], D[g[x^2], {x, k}]} /. x -> 0, {k, 1, 2 m}]
```

This code outputs:

```
{derivativeorder[1], 0, 0}
{derivativeorder[2], 2f'[0], 2g'[0]}
{derivativeorder[3], 0, 0}
{derivativeorder[4], 12f''[0], 12g''[0]}
{derivativeorder[5], 0, 0}
{derivativeorder[6], 120f^(3)[0], 120g^(3)[0]}
```

I guessed that the answer was $2m + 1$ which is correct although I don't understand why. I seem to be missing the bigger picture.

Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: In my opinion, order of contact is defined wrongly. Simple intersections should have order $1$, not $0$ (this would agree with the usual definition of the order of a zero of a function). If you define it that way, then you see that the order of contact doubles. To me, that's more intuitive, and maybe it is to you too.